# Invalid column name 'PaymentRecommendationId' even though column exists in table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the stored procedure which throws exception while alter operation after added extra matching parameter `AND PR.PaymentRecommendationId = InputJSON.PaymentRecommendationId)`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_PaymentRecommendationsInsertUpdate
@PaymentRecommendationsJson NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
    MERGE INTO PaymentRecommendations AS PR
    USING ( 
                SELECT      ClaimId,
                            CoverageTypeId,
                            Payee,
                            IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt,
                            ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt,
                            RequestDate,
                            Memo,
                            CheckNumber,
                            IssueDate,
                            CreatedOn,
                            CreatedBy,
                            ModifiedOn,
                            ModifiedBy
                FROM    OPENJSON(@PaymentRecommendationsJson)
                        WITH (
                                    PaymentRecommendationId BIGINT,
                                    ClaimId BIGINT,
                                    CoverageTypeId SMALLINT,
                                    Payee VARCHAR(256),
                                    IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt MONEY,
                                    ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt MONEY,
                                    RequestDate DateTime,
                                    Memo VARCHAR(512),
                                    CheckNumber VARCHAR(16),
                                    IssueDate DATETIME,
                                    CreatedOn DATETIME,
                                    CreatedBy BIGINT,
                                    ModifiedOn DATETIME,
                                    ModifiedBy BIGINT
                            )) AS InputJSON
               ON (PR.ClaimId = InputJSON.ClaimId AND PR.PaymentRecommendationId = InputJSON.PaymentRecommendationId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET  ClaimId = InputJSON.ClaimId,
                    CoverageTypeId = InputJSON.CoverageTypeId,
                    Payee = InputJSON.Payee,
                    IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt = InputJSON.IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt,
                    ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt = InputJSON.ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt,
                    RequestDate = InputJSON.RequestDate,
                    Memo = InputJSON.Memo,
                    CheckNumber = InputJSON.CheckNumber,
                    IssueDate = InputJSON.IssueDate,
                    ModifiedOn = GETUTCDATE(),
                    ModifiedBy = InputJSON.ModifiedBy
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (    ClaimId,
                    CoverageTypeId,
                    Payee,
                    IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt,
                    ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt,
                    RequestDate,
                    Memo,
                    CheckNumber,
                    IssueDate,
                    CreatedOn,
                    CreatedBy)
        VALUES (    InputJSON.ClaimId,
                    InputJSON.CoverageTypeId,
                    InputJSON.Payee,
                    InputJSON.IndemnityPmtRequestAmnt,
                    InputJSON.ExpensePaymentRequestAmnt,
                    InputJSON.RequestDate,
                    InputJSON.Memo,
                    InputJSON.CheckNumber,
                    InputJSON.IssueDate,
                    GETUTCDATE(),
                    InputJSON.CreatedBy)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
END
```

Below line causing error in above stored procedure:

`ON (PR.ClaimId = InputJSON.ClaimId AND PR.PaymentRecommendationId = InputJSON.PaymentRecommendationId)`

Error: `Invalid column name 'PaymentRecommendationId'.`

But `PaymentRecommendationId` column getting passed in json string as well as it is exists in table

Comment: Remove all the stuff that doesn't matter, and we will find the problem.

Comment: You also have to select PaymentRecommendationId from OPENJSON.

Comment: Your missing it in your select list

Comment: @plaidDK, Thanks that's working..!